# Unable to get properties from properties file?

Tags: java

I have written a class FetchProp that extends class PropMap which fetches the values from properties file.When i run FetchProp as junit test case it is giving me correct output i.e it fetches properties the way i want.Then i have created class CreateReport that calls a method of FetchProp which helps in generation of report.But when i run a test case on CreateReport the FetchProp is not fetching the properties as it used to do when run standalone?

Can any one suggest what may be the issue

PS: I have checked the path where properties file is placed and i am displaying the properties file path every time i run the program and file has the properties i want to get.

Comment: Can you post some sample code that shows the behaviour you are describing?

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on how you fetch your properties file. If you are using something like:

```
private Properties readProps() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File f = new File("c:\\path\\to\\file\\props.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(new FileInputStream(f));
    return props;
}
```

...then it might work in your unit tests but not when running the application. You might want to try something like:

```
private Properties readProps2() throws IOException  {
    InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("props.properties");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(stream);
    return props;
}
```

...which reads the file from the classpath instead.